# oblique asymptote of $\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{1+x}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying the oblique asymptote lines of the function:
$$\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{1+x}}$$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{1+x}}}{x}= 1$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x) -x=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \sqrt{\frac{x^3}{1+x}} -x= -\frac{1}{2}$ according to may calculation, while in my book it should be $-\frac{3}{2}$
$$\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{1+x}} -x= \frac{\frac{x^3}{1+x} -x^2}{\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{1+x}} +x}=   \frac{-\frac{x^2}{1+x} }{\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{1+x}} +x}  = - \frac{x^2}{1+x} \cdot  \frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{x^3}+x \sqrt{1+x}}  =  \frac{x}{x^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot  \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+1} \cdot x^{\frac{1}{2}}(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} +\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+1})}  \sim -\frac{1}{2}$$

I don't know where I'm making mistakes.

For $x$ tending to $- \infty$:
$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{1+x}}}{x}= -1$

and about the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x) +x$ the value should be $-\frac{3}{2}$ but I'm very uncertain because of the negativeness of $x$.

Comment: Your calculations are correct, it seems there's an error in your book.

Comment: $ \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x) +x \ $ should be $ \ +\frac12 \ $.  The answers in the book may be for a problem that was revised, or the solver really could have messed up.  About a third of a percent of textbook answers are wrong on average, in my experience.

Comment: According Wolframalpha] you are right. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bx%5Crightarrow+%2B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E3%7D%7B1%2Bx%7D%7D+-x